# Coffeescript "@" variables

Tags: coffeescript

What does it mean in Coffeescript when a variable name begins with an "@" sign?
For example, I've been looking through the hubot source code and just in the first few lines I've looked at, I found

```
class Brain extends EventEmitter
  # Represents somewhat persistent storage for the robot. Extend this.
  #
  # Returns a new Brain with no external storage.
    constructor: (robot) ->
    @data =
      users:    { }
      _private: { }

    @autoSave = true

    robot.on "running", =>
      @resetSaveInterval 5
```

I've seen it several other places, but I haven't been able to guess what it means.

Comment: In coffeescript @ means this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org)? Searching that for `@` would answer your question and probably teach you a few other things too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` symbol is a shorcut for `this` as you can see in [Operators and Aliases](http://coffeescript.org/#operators).

> As a shortcut for `this.property`, you can use `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that the “@” variables are instance variables of the class, that is, class members. Which souldn't be confused with class variables, that you can compare to static members.

Also, you can think of `@variables` as the `this` or `self` operators of OOP languages, but it's not the exact same thing as the old javascript `this`. That javascript `this` refer to the current scope, which causes some problems when your are trying to refer to the class scope inside a callback for example, that's why coffescript have introduced the `@variables`, to solve this kind of problem.

For example, consider the following code:

```
Brain.prototype = new EventEmitter();

function Brain(robot){

  // Represents somewhat persistent storage for the robot. Extend this.
  //
  // Returns a new Brain with no external storage.

    this.data = {
      users:    { },
      _private: { }
    };

    this.autoSave = true;    

    var self = this;

    robot.on('running', fucntion myCallback() {
      // here is the problem, if you try to call `this` here
      // it will refer to the `myCallback` instead of the parent
      // this.resetSaveInterval(5);
      // therefore you have to use the cached `self` way
      // which coffeescript solved using @variables
      self.resetSaveInterval(5);
    });
}
```

Final thought, the `@` these days means that you are referring to the class instance (i.e., `this` or `self`). So, `@data` basically means `this.data`, so, without the `@`, it would refer to any visible variable `data` on scope.